# howto install compiled package

Tags: dpkg

I compiled an upgraded source for a lesser package already installed.
How do I use dpkg or another to install and let the system upgrade system know about it

In system:

```
hdf5-tools    1.8.8-9
```

Compiled:

```
hdf5-1.9.145
```

Do I just `make install` as root or use a system package like `dpkg`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use make install as root.

```
sudo make install
```

Or if you prefer to make a .deb, use checkinstall

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
sudo checkinstall
```

This converts the source code into a .deb and installs it. It can later be removed with any package management (`apt-get`, `dpkg`, synaptic, package manager, etc).

See:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo